# How do I use mogrify convert only on files with a certain creation date?

Tags: command-line, files, wildcards, timestamps, mogrify

I'm creating an animated gif using mogrify's `convert`. However, at the moment I run in on a folder with dozens of images in it, and I just instruct it to use all of the images it finds. However, I'd like it to only use files that were created on a particular date. Can I do such a thing?

Current command used:

```
convert -delay 10 -loop 0 images/* animation.gif
```

All my filenames are timestamps so alternatively I'd like to be able to specify a range, something like:

```
convert -delay 10 -loop 0 --start="images/147615000.jpg" --end="images/1476162527.jpg" animation.gif
```

I've tried the `convert` man pages but no luck. Is any of this possible?

Comment: just to keep the next person from getting thrown off, I suspect your "images/147615000.jpg" was missing a zero at the end, to make it closer in epoch-seconds to 1476162527.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This small shell script will loop through every file in the current directory and compare it's last-modified timestamp to the range that is built by the `start` and `end` timestamps (here, October 10th). Matching files are added into the `files` array, and if there are any files in the array, it calls `convert` on them. Adjust the `-gt 0` to `-gt 1` if you want to have at least two files (or more).

Note that the creation time is not usually preserved in a file's (Unix) attributes, so this method could be fooled by a simple `touch 1476158400.jpg`, which would make an old file appear new. See below for a second option.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

start=$(date +%s -d 'Oct 10 2016')
end=$(date +%s -d 'Oct 11 2016')

files=()
for f in *
do
  d=$(stat -c%Z "$f")
  [[ $d -ge $start ]] && [[ $d -le $end ]] && files+=("$f")
done

[[ ${#files[*]} -gt 0 ]] && convert -delay 10 -loop 0 "${files[*]}" animation.gif
```

Alternatively, if the filenames themselves encode the creation timestamp, then you could use a brute-force loop to find them:

```
start=$(date +%s -d 'Oct 10 2016')
end=$(date +%s -d 'Oct 11 2016')
files=()
for((i=start;i<=end;i++)); do [[ -f "${i}.jpg" ]] && files+=("${i}.jpg"); done
[[ ${#files[*]} -gt 0 ]] && convert -delay 10 -loop 0 "${files[*]}" animation.gif
```

Comment: Both of these methods assume you have a GNU-ish `date` utility that accepts the `-d` option; the first solution also relies on the GNU `stat` utility. Both options rely on a shell that supports arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If your images where named slightly differently, like so:

```
images/147615000-000.jpg
images/147615000-001.jpg
... more images ...
images/147615000-090.jpg
```

You could then do this:

```
convert -delay 10 -loop 0 images/147615000-*.jpg animation.gif
```

But I'm guessing the images are a timestamp for a reason.

You could try something like this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# 
# Find images from $1 to $2 inclusive

if [ "$2" = "" ]
then
    echo "Pass the first and last file."
    exit
fi
# Basic file check
if [ ! -f "$1" ]
then
    echo "$1 not found."
    exit
fi
if [ ! -f "$2" ]
then
    echo "$2 not found."
    exit
fi

# Get the file list. Note: This will skip the first file.
list=`find "./" -type f -newer "${1}" -and -type f -not -newer "${2}"`

# Include the first image
list="./$1
$list"
# Sort the images as find may have them in any order
list=`echo "$list" | sort`

# create the animation.gif
convert -delay 10 -loop 0 $list animation.gif

# say something
echo "Done"
```

Place that script in the directory you want to create "animation.gif" and I'm assuming the images are in a sub-directory. You would call like so:

```
sh ./fromToAnimation.sh images/147615000.jpg images/1476162527.jpg
```

This will work so long as there are no spaces or other special characters in the file names or path.

Comment: Why not `xargs` together with `find` if you are going to include it on the commandline anyway? The interesting case is if the list is too long for the commandline ...

Comment: @dirkt You should post your answer. The command line limit on a modern Linux is often near 2MB, but yes, this could be an issue. I could not thing of a another cleaner way without more info from the OP.

Comment: Thanks. I accepted the other one because it does not require me to figure out which timestamp corresponds to which date (I can just state which date I want the images for), which makes it a bit more convenient. But thanks for the script!